# How can a function pointer in a shared library be called from julia

Tags: julia, shared-libraries

In Julia, we can call an ordinary (and exported) function from a shared library as follows:

```
libHnd=Libdl.dlopen("/Path/To/Lib.so")
funHnd=Libdl.dlsym(libHnd,"funName")
@ccall $funHdl()::Cvoid
```

However, let us assume that the library contains a variable for a function pointer which is exported, but the actual function is not exported. For instance:

```
static void funName(void);
void (*funPtr)(void)=funName;
```

In this case, how can I call the funPtr from Julia?

I am especially looking for a solution for the cases where the value of the funPtr can be changed dynamically by the library itself. (As a matter of fact, this is the reason, why the library only exports the function pointer rather than the function itself. libVolk is an example of such a use case).